# Change severity of log entries in GCP logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Is it possible to automatically change some properties of already logged entries (such as severity) automatically for old as well as for new logs in the future? For example I want to change severity from `warning` to `info` for all entries using regex (or exact match) on some field

Comment: There is already a filed [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271270202) for this. However, for feature requests there is no guarantee of any time frame for updates or that the requested feature will be implemented.

Comment: I am opposed to being able to modify Cloud Logging log entries. Log entries provide critical security and history information. I cannot see a scenario where that should be allowed or supported. If you require this feature, export the logs to another logging or data storage system and process each entry as you require.